# Prevent Postback with custom jQuery confirm implementation on asp:LinkButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

I have a `LinkButton` that executes on the server and changes the page.  Historically, I've had a `confirm` message box that executes `OnClientClick` to ensure the user would like to navigate away.

So far it looks like this:

**ASP.NET**:

```html
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ChangePage" Text="Change page"
                OnClientClick="confirm('are you sure you want to change page?');" 
                OnClick="Navigate" >
    Change Page
</asp:LinkButton>
```

**HTML Output**:

```html
<a id="MainContent_ChangePage" 
   onclick="confirm('are you sure you want to change page?');"
   href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ChangePage','')" >
    Change page
</a>
```

This all works fine like this. The trouble is that I'm trying to replace all confirm boxes with a prettier jQuery-UI implementation like this:

```js
window.confirm = function (message, obj) {
    $('<div/>')
    .attr({ title: 'Webpage Confirm'})
    .html(message)
    .dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                __doPostBack(obj, '');
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return true;
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I believe this has to do with the fact that the `confirm` dialog operates *synchronously*, while jQuery dialogs occur *asynchronously*.  However, I thought setting `modal: true` would cause it to wait for a response.

How can I override `window.confirm` to get consistent behavior?

Comment: remove `__doPostBack(obj, '');` (your link will do that it self) and do: `OnClientClick="return AreYouSure('my message');` and of course use the `AreYouSure` function... not a good idea? if you want to override the `confirm` method, you will need to do it cross-browser, and that might through you off...

Comment: Changed to `OnClientClick="return AreYouSure('message');"` but it still immediately posts back.  If I add any lines of code after the `.dialog()` declaration, they execute immediately.  So I think it's already well on it's way to the server before the 'OK' or 'Cancel' functions even get a chance to execute.

Comment: then use a normal link, and do the `__doPostBack` call where you have in the code and pass the id name... - see the source code and use that call in your modal confirmation: http://screencast.com/t/FufCsod3

Answer (score 0):

Add this to OK action:

```
    var href = $(obj).attr("href");
window.location.replace(href);
window.navigator.location(href);
return true;
```

And remove __postback line

it works with me